# Codeigniter SQL Query Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using [Codeigniter3](https://codeigniter.com/) and have a problem with an query

The default value of the variable `day` is `14`. I want to convert sql query below to the codeigniter model below.

```
(CONVERT_TZ(CreateTime,'+0:00','+9:00') > DATE_ADD( CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+0:00','+9:00') , INTERVAL -".$day." DAY )

OR CONVERT_TZ(CreateTime,'+0:00','+9:00') > DATE_ADD( CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+0:00','+9:00') , INTERVAL -".$day." DAY ) )
```

This is the model I wrote and it gives error

```
$where["CONVERT_TZ(CreateTime,'+0:00','+9:00') > DATE_ADD( CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+0:00','+9:00'),"] = "INTERVAL -".$day." DAY";

foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
   $this->db->where($key,$value);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this..

```
 $where = "(CONVERT_TZ(CreateTime,'+0:00','+9:00') > DATE_ADD( CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+0:00','+9:00') , INTERVAL -".$day." DAY )
           OR CONVERT_TZ(CreateTime,'+0:00','+9:00') > DATE_ADD( CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+0:00','+9:00') , INTERVAL -".$day." DAY ))";

  $this->db->where($where);
```

For more see [Codeigniter Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will look into Codeginiter Query Builder. However, I have tried your code and it still gives me same error.

Comment: Okay. here is my errors

You have an error : in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') OR CONVERT_TZ(CreateTime,'+0:00','+9:00') > DATE_ADD( CONVERT_TZ(NO' at line 3

Comment: Your current MySQL version does not support the `CONVERT_TZ()`.

Comment: Mysql version info : "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53"
It supported `CONVERT_TZ` function and it work..

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-convert_tz-function.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138076/discussion-between-hek-mat-and-learning).

Comment: This code works well
It was my mistake. I got rid of `)`.